# Can CLT be invoked to perform T-tests and other parametric tests on samples from a population that has non-normal distribution?

Tags: t-test, central-limit-theorem

I have data (about 1150 data points) and it is not normally distributed. Within this sample I want to compare means of two groups and see if they are significantly different. Can I use T-test for it, considering the fact that sampling distribution is normally distributed?

Comment: Yes, the CLT guarantees convergence of means towards normality, even when the observations themselves are not normal.

Comment: Thanks @Knarpie for the response. Does this mean, while comparing means, we can use parametric tests irrespective of the sample distributions?

Comment: Yes you could state it like that, if the means are calculated from a sufficiently large number of observations.